# EntityFramework Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Order Model**

```
public partial class Orden
    {
        public Orden()
        {
            this.Orden_Bitacora = new HashSet<Orden_Bitacora>();
        }    
        //Attributes list    
        public virtual ICollection<Orden_Bitacora> Orden_Bitacora { get; set; }
    }
```

**Orden_Bitacora Model**

```
public partial class Orden_Bitacora
    {
        public int IdBitacora { get; set; }
        public int IdOrden { get; set; }

        public virtual Orden Orden { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I try to create a `Order` always display me the message:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> The relationship 'OrdenexTModel.FK_Orden_Bitacora_Orden' was not
>   loaded because the type 'OrdenexTModel.Orden' is not available.

Its something wrong with the model declaration?

The relationship 'OrdenexTModel.FK_Orden_Bitacora_Orden' was not loaded because the type 'OrdenexTModel.Orden' is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cant find a Primary Key on Ordan and therefore the FK relationship will not work.
Add the PK to Orden

```
public partial class Orden
{
    public int OrdenId { get; set; }
    public Orden()
    {
        this.Orden_Bitacora = new HashSet<Orden_Bitacora>();
    }    
    //Attributes list    
    public virtual ICollection<Orden_Bitacora> Orden_Bitacora { get; set; }
}
```

and you may need to add [Key] attribute to your Orden_Bitacora PK as it doesnt follow the Entity Framework naming convention

```
[Key]  
public int IdBitacora { get; set; }
```

or

```
public int Orden_BitacoraId
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Go to EntityFramework .edmx file which will open an entity framework, Right click and select Update Model from Database, select okey it will get updated as changes might have done in database.